# How to draw the plane $x+y+2z=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

> I need to evaluate $$\iiint \text d x \text d y\text d z$$ the planes are $x=0,y=0,z=0,x+y+2z=2$

Is there a method to draw the plane? it is easy to draw $x=0,y=0$ and $z=0$ but how can I draw to myself $x+y+2z=2$? without using any calculator

Comment: In a perspective representation of 3D space, you can draw the three piercing points of the axis in the plane and join them by a triangle.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Why not write that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Good idea @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the point of intersection of the plane $x+y+2z=2$ with the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axis and then join the three point to form a triangle. The picture below illustrate the method.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the axonometric conventions, here is how you represent a plane in the first octant and one parallel to a coordinate plane.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ax+by+cz=d$. Assume $d\neq 0$ and divide by $d$:

$$\frac{a}{d}x+\frac{b}{d}x +\frac{c}{d}x =1 $$

or

$$\frac{x}{d/a}+\frac{y}{d/b}+\frac{z}{d/c}=1.$$

Now plug in $y=0,z=0$ to get $x=d/a$, $x=0,z=0$ to get $y=d/b$ and $x=0,y=0$ to get $z=d/c$. Note that these points are intersection points with the $x,y$ and $z$ axis, which are just written in the denominator.